# Anyone have experience with exposing Event type in Salesforce Lighting Web Component LWC for the Dynamic Interactions?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, lightning

I tried to expose the Event tab in the LWC. I followed this Help document from Salesforce: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_dynamic_interactions.htm&type=5&release=234

Here is another document that has more info on the process of creating this LWC: https://www.forcetrails.com/2021/08/publish-lwc-events-to-lightning-app-builder.html

I created the Apex Controller Class.

I was able to create and deeply the Contact list LWC

I'm stuck on the Account List LWC where the XML file is keep throwing me an error on the event.

Everything went well except when I tried to deploy the accountList.js-meta.xml. I personally have no experience in XML and very little experience in Apex and JS.

Here is the error message:

Invalid element name:
-Event

One of the following is expected:

- hasStep
- objects
- property
- propertyType
- SupportedFormFactors

I tried all of those expected values, and none of them is working.
Thank you in advance and any help and direction will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Please, share the error that you are getting and the content of the file so it's easier to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the error message:
Invalid element name:
-Event

One of the following is expected:
- hasStep
- objects
- property
- propertyType
- SupportedFormFactors

I tried all of those expected values, and none of them is working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey guys, I think it has something to do with my VSC XML extension. It started working after I uninstalled the XML extension pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message that you have mentioned, it looks like you have named that XML element as `Event`. Since XML is case-sensitive, could you please try it with the `event` tag? Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: That too with the XML extension pack unintalled. Now is all working thanks guys!!!